# Printing without calling method

Tags: java, object, inheritance

it may seem as a very basic question, but I do not understand why the method toString is printed on the screen when I didn't even called it, I just instantiated a Car object. Thanks

```
public class Car {

    public void m1() { 

       System.out.println("car 1"); 

    }

    public void m2() { 

       System.out.println("car 2"); 

    }

    public String toString() { 

       return "vroom"; 

    }

 }




public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car myCar = new Car();

    System.out.println(myCar);

}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 1):

The  `String.valueOf(Object)` method is called implicitly, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) of `println(Object x)`:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at
>   first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

and the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) of `String.valueOf(Object obj)`:

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the
>   value of obj.toString() is returned.

Answer (score 0):

In this line `System.out.println(myCar)` the [`toSring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) method is internally called because [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.Object-) *calls at first `String.valueOf(myCar)` to get the printed object's string value*. [`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-) uses `myCar.toString()` if `myCar` is not `null`.

So the full flow would be like this:

`System.out.println(myCar)` **>** `String.valueOf(myCar)` **>** `myCar.toString()`

Comment: Does it always call the toString method? That's what I don't understand

Comment: It always call toString method on any object. It will call default toString method if you don't override it.

Comment: @JoeVanjik it is worth to mention that it is always called as long as the argument is not `null`

Answer (score 0):

Because there's no `System.out.println(Car)` method, the Java compiler picks the closest match it can, which is [`System.out.println(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)). That calls [`String.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) on what you pass in to get the string version of it to print. `String.valueOf` uses the `toString` method of your object to get the string. From its documentation:

> **Returns:**
>
> if the argument is `null`, then a string equal to `"null"`; otherwise, the value of `obj.toString()` is returned.